# Scrape HTML Table in Python

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrape

I am trying to scrape the SEC report page to pull some basic info on a number of tickers.

Here is an example URL for Apple - https://sec.report/CIK/0000320193

Within the page is a 'Company Details' table which includes basic info. I am essentially trying to just scrape the IRS Number, State of Incorp and Address.

I am cool with just scraping this chart and saving it into a PD Df. I am very new to web scraping so looking for some tips to make this work! Below is my code, but I don't know where to go once I extract the panel body. Thanks guys!

```
session = requests.Session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get('https://sec.report/CIK/0000051143.html', headers = headers)
page.content

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

soup.find_all(class_='panel-body')
```

Comment: _I don't know where to go once I extract the panel body._ That's incredibly vague, can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of BeautifoulSoup try with lxml package, for me it's easier to find elements with xpath sentences:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

session = requests.Session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get('https://sec.report/CIK/0000051143', headers=headers)

raw_html = html.fromstring(page.text)

irs = raw_html.xpath('//tr[./td[contains(text(),"IRS Number")]]/td[2]/text()')[0]

state_incorp = raw_html.xpath('//tr[./td[contains(text(),"State of Incorporation")]]/td[2]/text()')

address = raw_html.xpath('//tr[./td[contains(text(),"Business Address")]]/td[2]/text()')[0]
```

Comment: Thank you for this! When I run the code I receive an IndexError. 'List index out of range'. Are you seeing the same?

Comment: That's because the xpath fails, and the element is not found, in the example above worked for me.

Comment: Thats strange, I wonder why the xpath is failing for me but working successfully on your end.